# No C++ project in Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

My visual studio 2008 have only Fortran option as can be seen in new project windows in the Figure, How can I add C++ projects to the visual studio 2008. [image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you did not install it.

Got to add/remove programs. Find VS2008. Click change/repair. Select the c++ option(s)

Comment: This visual studio has comes with the intel fortran compliers so have no C++ or other option,  can I add C++ to this.